# Correct CSS layout, z-index problem, custom nav-bar

Tags: css, cross-browser, z-index, dreamweaver

I am new to web design.  I am learning CSS and really like the possibilities of it.  My problems are probably pretty simple fixes,  but I cannot seem to find the answers to them.

I want to have a good start with CSS and that means having a good layout.  What happens is I design my sites and get them all set-up in DW.  I start building the CSS and when I test them I get the z-index error for ie6, 7.  I have things positioned in absolute and relative.  Things appear/disappear.  I make my nav bars in FW so they are custom designs.  They work great with rollover effects,  export them to DW and then I get problems.

Can someone help me understand the error of my ways?  I can show you the code if that will help?  I know I will become a full on CSS proponent as I do not want to start off learning with tables,  I have heard the horror stories of this old and complicated system.

Thanks for helping this newbie.

Comment: DW = dreamweaver. FW = ?.
If you can post a link with an example page it would help a lot. Otherwise, please post example code along with your CSS.
I assume that when you say z-index error you mean things are not appearing the in the correct z-order. This is really hard (impossible?) to debug without more concrete information.

Comment: you need to paste the code that is troubling you, the z-index part at least.

Comment: What is DW short for? edit Dreamweaver

Answer (score 1):

Z-index problems in IE are quite frustrating.

You need to consider the z-index wrapping your elements are much as you have for the elements themselves.

With the following pesudo-code, in IE you need to ensure the **menu wrapper** had a higher z-index than the **page contents**, even though the menu itself has a higher z-index than everything else. It behaves as if elements within elements start a NEW stacking order (ignoring the true z-index). To get around this the z-index of your wrappers takes precedence.

```
<-- page wrapper -->   (give z-index of 1) 
    <-- menu wrapper -->  (give z-index of 10)   
         <-- menu -->    
    <-- end menu wrapper --> (give z-index of 2)   
    <-- page contents -->    
    ...    
    <-- end page contents -->    
<-- end page wrapper -->
```